# How to install a bleach module without using npm install?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, bleach

I am getting some proxy error when running below command:

```
npm install bleach
```

Is there any alternative to download this modules and add under node_modules
or any other alternative for this. Please help

Comment: you can install that bleach in different machine. and copy the bleach folder from node module folder and paste it where you want

Comment: Or simply download it from its url and paste it in your node modules